# how to pass xFile as a function parameter in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, http

I want to upload images to the server using flutter and HTTP package. I am able to display user-selected images but I want to upload them to the server but when I try to pass the image file to the function it gives me an error.

**Image Picker Code :**

```
 XFile? uploadimage;
  final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
  Future<void> chooseImage() async {
    var chooseImage = await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    setState(() {
      uploadimage = chooseImage;
    });
  }
```

**services file code **

```
 AdminSupervisorServices.createNewSupervisor(
                                    _nameController.text,
                                    _emailController.text,
                                    _addressController.text,
                                    _siteController.text,
                                    _mobileController.text,
                                    _passwordController.text,
                                    uploadimage // error here
)
```

**function body**

```
 static createNewSupervisor(String name, String email, String address,
      String site, String mobileNumber, String password, File? image) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    List<int> imageBytes = image!.readAsBytesSync();
    String baseimage = base64Encode(imageBytes);
    var token = prefs.getString("token");
    var response = await http
        .post(Uri.parse("$baseURL/api/mmmmmmmm"), headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
    }, body: {
      "full_name": name,
      "address": address,
      "mobile_no": mobileNumber,
      "email": email,
      "site_name": site,
      "password": password,
      "image": baseimage,
    });
    print(response.body.toString());
    var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
    return data;
  }
...
}
```

Comment: Due to the function you are indicating **"File? image"** which is not XFile so try to change it to **"XFile? image"**  or just pass the string which is the path.

Comment: can you provide me some code snippets ??

Comment: ` List<int> imageBytes = image.readAsBytesSync(); ` getting error at this line sir.

Comment: I usually dont use XFile as my image but rather only File since both is same with the import of dart.io wait gonna write down

Comment: what is your uploading code then?

Answer (score 1):

```
try this
if this work

    import 'dart:io';
    /////// Import for File

     final File uploadimage = File("");
     final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
      
    Future<void> chooseImage() async {
        var chooseImage = await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
        setState(() {
          uploadimage = File(chooseImage.path);
        });
      }
    
    the function you have
    
    AdminSupervisorServices.createNewSupervisor(
                                    _nameController.text,
                                    _emailController.text,
                                    _addressController.text,
                                    _siteController.text,
                                    _mobileController.text,
                                    _passwordController.text,
                                    uploadimage 
);
    
    static createNewSupervisor(String name, String email, String address,
          String site, String mobileNumber, String password, File? image)async{
    ...
    }
```

Edit:

if you are passing image to a json
then you missing out  is **data:image/png;base64** something like this
lets assume this function return string.

```
///include import path
import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;
///////////////////////////////////////


imagetobase64(String? imagePath){
    final extension = path.extension(imagePath
        .substring(imagePath.lastIndexOf("/"))
        .replaceAll("/", ""));
//// the extension return is png or jpg or jpeg which is needed
      final bytes = File(imagePath).readAsBytesSync();
      String base64 =
          "data:image/${extension.replaceAll(".", "")};base64,${base64Encode(bytes)}";

   return base64;

}
```

Comment: I have updated the question sir. Now I am getting error while uploading image. rest working fine.

Comment: Okay, wait gonna read it

Comment: what was the error when uploading image.

Comment: I am checking at backend whether image is recieving from client side but i am getting that no image is being sent from the client side.

Comment: Are you sending image on json format or form? try to check my edit answer for sending json image

Comment: @swapnilmane just mention me if its no work or it did work

Answer (score 0):

uploadimage is of type XFile?  and you are passing it to a function which accepts parameter of File? type

Comment: How can I convert xFile to file while passing to function ? I looked for it but have not found any suggestion.

Comment: `File(uploadimage.path) `
u can convert like this